# Why is file named "a.out" when compiling C++ file?

Tags: c++

Why does c++ automatically name the file "a.out"? Is there some significance to this?

```
$ g++ day2-operators.cpp 
$ ls
a.out  day2-operators.cpp  precision.cpp
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a.out is a file format used in older versions of Unix-like computer operating systems for executables, object code, and, in later systems, shared libraries. The name stands for "assembler output" - Wikipedia

You could call it tradition.